# How to deal with identity columns while insertion in MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am learning MVC & have a demo MVC application, where I am trying to save UserId, Name & Email.

UserId is int primary key & identity as well.

In my create view page I have fields for Name & Email only. But on post It's taking default value of int(0) for UserId as well and hence I am getting following exception.

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Users' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

Here is my Model class:

```
 namespace LearningMvc.Models
 {
 public class Users
 {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
    [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+",
    ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here's my action method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "UserId")] Users NewUser)
    {
        try
        {
            var ObjDbContext = new MyDbDataContext();
            ObjDbContext.Users.InsertOnSubmit(NewUser);
            ObjDbContext.SubmitChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
    }
```

Connection string in config

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="DemoDbForMvcConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=RASHMITAD7;Initial Catalog=DemoDbForMvc;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Here's dbml file:

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Database Name="DemoDbForMvc" Class="MyDbDataContext" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/linqtosql/dbml/2007">
    <Connection Mode="WebSettings" ConnectionString="Data Source=RASHMITAD7;Initial Catalog=DemoDbForMvc;Integrated Security=True" SettingsObjectName="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings" SettingsPropertyName="DemoDbForMvcConnectionString" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <Table Name="dbo.[Users]" Member="Users">
      <Type Name="Users">
        <Column Name="UserId" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false"/>
        <Column Name="Name" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(100)" CanBeNull="true" />
        <Column Name="Email" Type="System.String" DbType="NVarChar(50)" CanBeNull="true" />
      </Type>
    </Table>
  </Database>
```

Comment: How to update a model? may be my Db side changes are not reflecting...

Comment: I'm having some trouble re-producing your error. It works swell over here. Is there something with your `MyDbDataContext` or connectionString in web.config maybe? Can you please add those to your question?

Comment: Try adding few more annotations, [Column(Storage="_OrderID", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)] on user id. Let me know if it solves the issue

Comment: getting compilation error for all the properties like...

System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute' does not contain a definition for 'Storage'. Do  need to add some reference?

Answer (score 1):

I am not too familiar with dbml, so I will purpose a slightly different solution to get you started. What this basically does is keeping your model as it is, and uses the strongly typed data in the class to create the database:

ConnectionString:

```
<add name="DemoDbForMvcConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=RASHMITAD7;Initial Catalog=DemoDbForMvc;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Model:

```
public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address")]
        [RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+",
        ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

Data Context:

```
public class DataContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }

        public DataContext() : base("DemoDbForMvcConnectionString") { }
    }
```

MVC Action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "UserId")] Users user)
{
    var context = new DataContext();
    context.Users.Add(user);
    context.SaveChanges();

    return View();
}
```

You can add your dbml settings as data annotation on your model.